# Android App Chromecast Indication for Play Store

Tags: android, chromecast

How does Google Play Store know that your app supports Chromecast? There is no category, when publishing an app, to indicate that it's a Chromecast supporting app. I've added support for Chromecast to my app and updated description, but the app does not show up under the Chromecast category.

Thank You,
Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enter the sender details in the Google Cast Developer console: https://cast.google.com/publish/

The sender data is used to list your app as a Google Cast device in the store and on chromecast.com/apps

Comment: There is no option to enter Sender details, only details for the Custom and Styled Media Receivers. I am using Default Receiver.

Comment: You will have to use the Styled Media Receiver or a custom receiver to have your app listed.